# Neo4j NodeJS Parallel Executions

Tags: node.js, neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to run Neo4J on NodeJS using parallel executions.
I either get Socket Error, or EM Error, on ECONNETION RESET when running multiple.

"getaddrinfo EMFILE neo4j.dev.com:7687"
or:

error in neo4jSession.run()Error: Connection was closed by server

and others.

Is there any common correct way to queue alot of parallel executions while no overloading the session?

Here is my code - which doesn't work.

```js
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver').v1;
var Neo4jConfigurator = require("./config/Neo4jConfigurator.js").Neo4jConfigurator;
var Promise = require("bluebird");

var url = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getDBURlIndexer();
var userName = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getUserName();
var password = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getPassword();
var requestPromise = require("request-promise");


var Neo4jSession = function()
{
    this.masterDriver = null;
    this.defaultDriver = this.setDefaultDriver();
    this.activeSessions = {};
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.getActiveSessions  = function(){
    return this.activeSessions;
}


Neo4jSession.prototype.getMasterDriver  = function(){
    return this.masterDriver;
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.setMasterDriver  = function(endPoint){
    var boltPort = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getBoltPort();
    this.masterDriver = neo4j.driver("bolt://" + endPoint + ":" + boltPort ,  neo4j.auth.basic(userName, password),{encrypted:false, connectionPoolSize : 10});
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.setDefaultDriver  = function(){
  var url = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getDBURlIndexer();
  var driver = neo4j.driver("bolt://" + url,  neo4j.auth.basic(userName, password),  {encrypted:false, connectionPoolSize : 10});
  return driver;
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.getDefaultDriver  = function(){
  return this.defaultDriver;
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.addDefaultSession  = function(){
  var driver =  this.getDefaultDriver();
  var session = driver.session();
  return session;
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.run  = function(cypherQuery){
  var session = this.addDefaultSession();
  this.addActiveSession(session);
  return session.run(cypherQuery);
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.runMasterSession  = function(cypherQuery){
  var driver = this.getMasterDriver();
  var masterSession = driver.session();
  this.addActiveSession(masterSession);
  return  masterSession.run(cypherQuery);
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.closeAllSessions  = function(){
  var neo4jSessionObj = this;
  Object.keys(this.getActiveSessions()).forEach(function(activeSessionId){
    neo4jSessionObj.getActiveSessions()[activeSessionId].close();
    delete neo4jSessionObj.getActiveSessions()[activeSessionId];
    //console.log('deleted session ' + activeSessionId);
  })
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.getActiveSessions  = function(){
  return this.activeSessions;
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.addActiveSession  = function(session){
  var neo4jSessionObj = this;
  var activeSessionsNumber = Object.keys(this.getActiveSessions()).length + 1;
  this.getActiveSessions()[activeSessionsNumber] = session;
  //console.log('added session ' + activeSessionsNumber);
}

Neo4jSession.prototype.initMaster  = function()
{
  var neo4jSessionObj = this;
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      Promise.each(Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getEndPoints(), function(endPoint){
          var masterRoute = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getMasterRoute();
          var httpPort = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getHttpPort();
          var boltPort = Neo4jConfigurator.instance().getBoltPort();
          options =  {    uri : 'http://' + endPoint + ":" + httpPort + masterRoute ,                                    
                          method: "GET",
                          headers: 
                          {
                              'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8'
                          }
                      }
          requestPromise(options)
          .then(function(body){
              try
              {
                  body = body.replace(/\0/g,' ');
                  json = JSON.parse(body);
                  if(json == true)
                  {             
                      neo4jSessionObj.setMasterDriver(endPoint);                                               
                      resolve(endPoint);             
                  }
              }
              catch(err)
              {
                reject(err)
              }
          })
          .catch(function(err){
            if(! err.error || err.error != 'false')
              reject(err);
          })  
      })
  })
}



module.exports = {
  Neo4jSession: Neo4jSession
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot of (duplicate) code, what exactly does not work?

You don't need to keep sessions around, you can discard them after your query ran.

Also within a session / transaction you can use async.serial to run several queries one after the other.
Or if you want to batch queries / updates you can prepend your query with

`UNWIND {data} as row MATCH ...`

And pass a `{data:[ {foo:bar}, {foo:bar2}, ...]}` parameter with eg. 10k objects.

Comment: Can you share an example of both solutions?